# Apache Zookeeper not able to read config file, despite providing one

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

When I start up the Apache Zookeper with this command:

`sudo ./zookeeper-server-start.sh ../config/zookeeper.properties`

I notice that on startup, it will emit this warning:

`[2018-06-27 11:21:47,038] WARN Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running  in standalone mode (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)`

There's not much in there, but I have double checked, and the config is indeed there. Here is its contents:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# disable the per-ip limit on the number of connections since this is a non-production config
maxClientCnxns=0
```

What lead me to this discover is that I am actually currently having issues where my Brokers and Zookeepers both are randomly shutting down, without reason. The only reason for the shutdown I am given is:

`Signal was killed at: [2018-06-27 13:39:52,423] INFO Terminating process due to signal SIGHUP (kafka.Kafka$)`

But that's probably another question - my real question is - why can't my Kafka zookeeper find and keep its config that I am feeding it as a parameter?

Comment: It says it cannot be find a quorum, which is true until you start 3 Zookeeper servers

Comment: Then that makes sense, as we are only running one zookeeper server at the moment (it's a dev environment).